# Any Open Data Sets for the (Football) Euro Cup (in France 2016)?

Tags: data-request, sports, football

Are there any public data sets for the European Championship "Euro" Cup in France 2016?

Didn't find anything for download on the official UEFA site (besides a single-page PDF booklet for the match schedule).

Ideally the data set includes groups, teams, players, squads, matches, stadiums and so on and is in an **open plain text** format such as CSV (comma-separated values), JSON (javascript objects), SQL (structured query language), etc.

Any insight appreciated. Cheers.

**(Update Jun/14th)** Kick off! Any news?

PS:  Disclosure: I'm the project lead of the football.db project collecting open public domain football data e.g.

- [`openfootball/euro-cup`](https://github.com/openfootball/euro-cup) Euro Cup Datasets (1960-2020) - not complete in any way :-(

Comment: Have you tried contacting UEFA? Also: http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/ gives the matches, stadiums, dates and results (so far)

Comment: Good point. Not sure what you expect from contacting UEFA? It's big business. Do you think UEFA will give away the data for free to anyone without any restrictions? Please read the fine print e.g. © 2016 UEFA. All rights reserved. PS: To learn more about open (data) licensing see http://opendefinition.org for example.

Comment: Their interest is in promoting the Euro Cup, if they think giving you that data helps their interest they might just give it to you.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow your logic. Sorry to break the news - the interest of the UEFA is in making money - why not ask if you can get free live streams for the matches too - it helps to promote the Euro Cup ;-)